# Calculating standard deviation not executing loop

Tags: javascript

I've just started learning coding on code academy and I'm really new to this.

I'm trying to make this program ask the user for values which it adds to an array from which it calculates the sample standard deviation.

```
// This array stores the values needed
var figures;

getStandardDeviation = function() {

// I need at least two figures for a standard deviation
figures[0] = prompt("Enter a number:");
figures[1] = prompt("Enter a number:");

// Checks whether user wishes to add more values to the array
var confirm = prompt("Would you like to add another? (Y or N)").toUpperCase();

// I can't figure out why the following if statement is not executed
// It checks whether the user wishes to add more values and adds them to the array
// If not it breaks the for loop
if (confirm === "Y"){
    for ( i = 0; i === 100; i++){
        figures[i + 2] = prompt("Enter a number:");
        confirm = prompt("Would you like to add another figure? (Y or N)").toUpperCase();
        if (confirm === "N"){
            break;
        }
    }
}

// The rest of the code works fine from here onwards

var sumx = 0;
var n = figures.length;
for(var i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    sumx += figures[i];
}
console.log("Sum = " + sumx);

var sumXsq = 0;    
for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    sumXsq += (figures[i] * figures[i]);
}    
console.log("Sum x squared = " + sumXsq);

var sxx = (sumXsq - (sumx * sumx)/n);
console.log("Sxx = " + sxx);

var v = sxx/(n - 1);
console.log("Variance = " + v);

var standardDev = Math.sqrt(v);
console.log("Standard Deviation = " + standardDev);

};

getStandardDeviation();
```

The program is supposed to ask me if I want to add more values to the array, then when I confirm, it gives me a prompt to add more values.

Currently, when I execute the program I input the numbers 56 and 67. The code then asks me if I wish to add more values, I then confirm this. Instead of letting me add more values it ignores this and calculates the standard deviation with the first two values (56 and 67).

```
The output is:

Sum = 05667
Sum x squared = 7625
Sxx = -16049819.5
Variance = -16049819.5
Standard Deviation = NaN
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a very helpful description.  Please give us an example of input, output, and expected output.

Comment: You can use `confirm()` instead of `prompt()` when asking a user a yes or no question. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21135386/1317805.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for ( i = 0; i === 100; i++){[...]}` means

1. Set `i` to 0
2. If it's not true that `i === 100` (that is: if `i` is not 100), end the loop
3. Do whatever I put inside the {} braces, once
4. Do `i++`
5. Back to 2

As the initial value for `i` is 0 and not 100, the code inside the loop is never executed. If you want it to go from 0 to 99, it should be `for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++)`.

You don't actually need a for loop, though. A while loop would be better. A loop like `while (true){[...]}` would run until it hit a `break` statement. As you wouldn't have the `i` in that case, you could use `figures.push(parseFloat(prompt("Enter a number:")))` instead (you should use `parseFloat`, as per what [Vincent Hogendoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21135497/3191224) said) . `push` adds a new value at the end of an array, so it's exactly what you need. Something like:

```
if (confirm === "Y"){
    while (true){
        figures.push(parseFloat(prompt("Enter a number:")));
        confirm = prompt("Would you like to add another figure? (Y or N)").toUpperCase();
        if (confirm === "N"){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also change it so it doesn't ask if you want to stop if you don't have at least two values. That way you would be able to leave out that first part:

```
figures[0] = prompt("Enter a number:");
figures[1] = prompt("Enter a number:");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `figures` variable isn't defined as an array. Because of this `figure[1] = prompt(...)` never gets hit and a TypeError is thrown on `var n = figures.length;`.

Change:

```
var figures;
```

To:

```
var figures = [];
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/MQ6a7/).

You can then replace the `for` loop you're using after `if (confirm === "Y")` with a recursive function:

```
// Push a user input number into the figures array
figures.push(prompt("Enter a number:"));

// Function to add a new number and ask if we want to add more
function addNewNumber() {
    // Push a new user input number into the figures array
    figures.push(prompt("Enter a number:"));

    // Ask if the user wants to add another number
    if (confirm("Do you want to add another number?"))
        // If they do, call this function again
        addNewNumber();
}

// Trigger the function for the first time
addNewNumber();
```

[**JSFiddle demo with recursion**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/MQ6a7/3/).

Comment: " and a TypeError is thrown on var n = figures.length;" The code fails well before that, that line won't be executed to throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

indeed your `figures` variable isn't defined as an array, like @James Donnely says.
Keep in mind you also fill in strings, so if you want to add up values you have to convert them to values.

you can use something like `parseFloat` for this.

if you don't use it, you sum up strings. 3+4 will be 34 instead of 7.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function StandardDeviation(numbersArr) {
    //--CALCULATE AVAREGE--
    var total = 0;
    for(var key in numbersArr) 
       total += numbersArr[key];
    var meanVal = total / numbersArr.length;
    //--CALCULATE AVAREGE--
  
    //--CALCULATE STANDARD DEVIATION--
    var SDprep = 0;
    for(var key in numbersArr) 
       SDprep += Math.pow((parseFloat(numbersArr[key]) - meanVal),2);
    var SDresult = Math.sqrt(SDprep/numbersArr.length);
    //--CALCULATE STANDARD DEVIATION--
    alert(SDresult);
    
}

var numbersArr = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
StandardDeviation(numbersArr);
```